# IFrames & Adsense flicker/reload when page loads - cause and solution?

Tags: html, iframe, ads, adsense, flicker

The problem here is when I have a few iframes and ads on the page - I see them flicker (like they are reloading) a few times until all are loaded. Besides looking horrible, they also also cause my ads to disappear after one or two flickers.

The disappearing ads occurs randomly between different computers and browsers. Usually one ad will disappear and the other one stays.

I tried nesting each of them in divs but it didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I have a script which change the innerHTML, causing the iframes and scripts to reload.